# Javascript Remove a Template Element

Tags: javascript, templates

I have a template that I will simplify as follows:

```html
<script type="text/template" id="contactTemplate">
  <div id="contactentry" class="row contact-info">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name1">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" name="Contacts[{{ID}}].FirstName" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group minus">
   <label for="contactMinus{{ID}}">&nbsp;</label>
   <a id="depminus{{ID}}"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>Remove</a>
   </div>
</script>
```

I allow insertion of the template, multiple times via the following code, this part works:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var clone = (function () {
    var cloneIndex = -1;
    var template = $('#contactTemplate').text();
    return function () {
      //Replace all instances of {{ID}} in our template with the cloneIndex.
      return template.replace(/{{ID}}/g, ++cloneIndex);
    }
  })();//self executing function.
  var contacts = $('#contacts')
  $("#contactadd").on("click", function () {
    contacts.append(clone());
    window.controlManager.FindControls(contacts);
  });
</script>

          <div id='contacts'>
            <div class="col col-lg-1">
              <a id="contactadd"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Add</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Now I am trying to figure out how to make javascript code to remove each element when/if the minus button is clicked (in the template).

I'm not sure what kindof code I could then use to delete the contacts, via the depminus{{ID}} control. Any tips to get me started?

Comment: One of the things you'll want to do is to either stop using "id" attributes in the template, or else use parameterized "id" values. You can't have multiple elements with the same "id" in the DOM without things getting weird.

Comment: My insert code adds an incremental ID to the element, so each one is unique, I do believe.